# MySQL - how to speed up SELECT SUM

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization, query-performance

I have a MySQL table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `goods_flow` (
 `cycle_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `subject_id` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `origin_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `flow_value` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`cycle_id`,`origin_id`,`subject_id`),
 KEY `fk_goods_flow_subjects` (`subject_id`),
 KEY `fk_goods_flow_origins` (`origin_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

and the application often uses this query:

```
SELECT SUM(flow_value) AS 'amount_of_goods' FROM goods_flow WHERE subject_id = 'xyz';
```

which takes a long time.

How could I speed up the query execution?
Thank You

Comment: (1) What is "long time"? (2) please attach execution plan

Comment: For such a simple query to be slow, just means it does a full table scan. The first thing that comes to mind is putting a non-unique index on subject_id.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz: long time is about 0.5 s, which is one of the highest values in my SQL queries log.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz: Execution plan https://s15.postimg.org/vti8xt6i3/explain.png

Comment: The execution plans object names does not match the DDL you have provided.

Comment: I know, I am sorry, I wanted to translate it to english. toky_kapitaloveho_zbozi_sklad = goods_flow and the index on bottom of the image is fk_goods_flow_subjects

Comment: What are the results of `SELECT count(*) FROM goods_flow WHERE subject_id = 'xyz';` and `SELECT count(*) FROM goods_flow`?

Comment: first query: 57, second query: 7260

Comment: please post the result from this 4 queries :**SET profiling=ON;
EXECUTE YOUR QUERY;
SHOW PROFILE ALL;
SET profiling=OFF;**

Comment: Does the rest of your queries use only subsets of the following columns: `cycle_id`,`origin_id`,`subject_id`?

Comment: @BerndBuffen It does not return anything.

Comment: @Pavel Straka - which System and MySQL Version you are using see : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html

Answer (score 3):

This is your query:

```
SELECT SUM(flow_value) AS amount_of_goods
FROM goods_flow
WHERE subject_id = 'xyz';
```

You can speed this query by using a composite index.  The best index is `goods_flog(subject_id, flow_value)`.  This index is a *covering* index for the query, meaning that all the data needed by the query is in the index, so the original data pages do not need to be accessed.

Comment: Pavel -- will `flow_value` be `UPDATEd` frequently?  If so, such an index may not be wise.  Else, it is the best index.

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason for the order of the 3 columns in the `PRIMARY KEY`?  If not, then shuffle them so that `subject_id` is first.  (And fiddle with the secondary keys.)

If it is taking 500ms to read 57 rows, then it sounds like a *very* cold cache.  What happens if you run it twice in a row?

What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  It is the relevant cache.  And how much RAM do you have?